# React control flow for manually entered route

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have a App component with all the routes defined as below;

```
function App() {
//some logic for state including canShow which is a boolean and shows routes only if it is true
{canShow && (
<Route exact path="/Route1">
<Comp1 />
</Route>
<Route exact path="/Route2">
<Comp2 />
</Route>
)
}
```

Now say if user is currently on localhost/#/Route1 and manually enters URL i.e. say to localhost/#/Route2, the control seems to be jumping directly to Comp2

I also have props.history.listen() setup in a child component of App (outside all the Route definitions). So basically this listen is in a direct child component of App.

Is there any way by which on manually entering the URL, I can ensure that the control first always goes to App.js...So that I can update the logic for setting "canShow" and if canShow is false, I do not render any child component and also the control does not go Comp1 or Comp2

Also control to props.history.listen callback when navigating via links, but with direct URL entry, it does not seem to be going to props.history.listen first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useHistory` hook to let your `App` component update on history changes. This hook returns the history object with a location property.

In the App component, you can add an `useEffect` to determine your `canShow` state and update it when needed.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [canShow, setCanShow] = useState(true);
  const history = useHistory();
  
  useEffect(() => {
      if (history.location.pathname === '/Route1') {
        setCanShow(true);
      }
  }, [history])
  
  //some logic for state including canShow which is a boolean and shows routes only if it is true
  return canShow && (
    <Route exact path="/Route1">
      <Comp1 />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/Route2">
      <Comp2 />
    </Route>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris...So I currently have props.history.listen() setup in one of my direct child component of App...So you think instead of that I should use useEffect and check for [history] changes ?

Comment: Yes, with hooks there is no need to add a `listen` event handler :-)

Comment: Oh k...But the UI behavior can vary between the 2 approaches (specifically in terms of when user is manually updating the URL)

Comment: Actually I tried this...For some reason, on URL chages (both link click or manually entering), the useEffect callback is not getting trigerred.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example?